# Why do I suddenly have a merge commit in my pushes?

Tags: git, git-merge, git-commit, git-revert, team-explorer

Well, I seem to have gone and mucked something up.

Until just recently, I used to be able to do a merge commit and then push to origin without that separate commit showing up. Now that it does, the merge commit is all I can see at my pipeline:

[image: Pipeline commits after]

Before this started, only the manual commit was pushed to origin (or at least showed as such):

[image: Pipeline commits before]

Here's Team Explorer (VS 2019 v16.6.5), after the behavior changed:

[image: Team Explorer]

...and here's my local branch history:

[image: Branch history]

See the change?

This all started right after I reverted commit `a13adadf`, fixed it and republished it. Now I've got some sort of weird branching effect going on, and I don't know how to get things back to where they were before. (I tried researching the problem, but the signal-to-noise ratio is very low when searching on anything related to `merge commit`.)

How can I get my repo to 'ignore' (i.e. stop displaying) the merge commits?

(Note: I'm the only dev working on this repo.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It seems likely that you were doing fast-forward operations before.  The `git merge` command will do this *instead* of merging, provided conditions are correct:

1. A fast-forward needs to be possible.
2. You are required to *avoid* the `--no-ff` option, which would disable the fast-forward.

> This all started right after I reverted commit `a13adadf`, fixed it and republished it.

This must have created a branch.  There's a problem with this word—"branch", that is—that will lead you astray here, but the graph snippet you show in your question indicates that this is in fact what happened.

> How can I get my repo to 'ignore' (i.e. stop displaying) the merge commits?

If you just want to avoid *displaying* them, there may be some option to your viewer to do this.

If you want to go back to not *making* them—the situation you were in before—you need to eliminate the branch you made.

## Long: What's going on here (and why the word "branch" is problematic)

The first thing to keep in mind is that Git is all about commits.  People new to Git, or even those who have been using it for quite a while, often think that Git is about files, or branches.  But it isn't, really: it's about *commits*.

Each commit is numbered, but the numbers are not simple counting numbers.  Instead, each commit gets a random-looking—but not actually random at all—*hash ID*.  These things are big and ugly, and Git will abbreviate them at times (as for instance your `a13adadf`), but each one of these is a numeric ID for some Git object—in this case, for a Git commit.

Git has a big database of all of its objects, which it can look up by ID.  If you give Git a commit number, it finds that commit's contents, by the ID.

The *contents* of a commit come in two parts:

- First, there's a snapshot of all the files that Git knows about.  This tends to be the bulk of most commits, except for one thing: the files are stored in a special, read-only, Git-only, compressed and de-duplicated format.  When you make a new commit in which most of the files are mostly the same as some *previous* commit, the new commit doesn't actually store the files *again*.  It just re-uses the existing files.  In other words, a particular version of a particular file gets amortized across however many commits re-use it.  The re-use is safe *because* the files are read-only.
- Besides the saved snapshot, each commit stores some *metadata:* information about the commit itself.  This includes the name and email address of the person who made the commit, and some date-and-time information, and so on.  Notably, the metadata for each commit also stores, for Git's use, the commit number—the hash ID—of the commit or commits that come right *before* this particular commit.  Git calls this the *parent* or, for a merge commit, *parents* of the commit.

What this does is allow Git to work *backwards*.  So that is how Git does work, backwards.  If we have a long string of commits, all in a row, like this:

```
... <-F <-G <-H
```

where `H` stands for the actual hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain, Git will start with commit `H`, reading it out of its object database.  Inside commit `H`, Git will find all the saved files, and also the hash ID of earlier commit `G`.  If Git needs it, Git will use this hash ID to read commit `G` out of the object database.  That gives Git the earlier snapshot, and also the hash ID of even-earlier commit `F`.

If Git needs to, Git will use hash ID `F` (as stored in `G`) to read `F`, and of course `F` contains another parent hash ID as well.  So in this manner, Git can start with the *last* commit and work backwards.

This leaves Git with one problem: how will it quickly find the hash ID of the *last* commit in the chain?  This is where *branch names* come in.

#### A branch name just holds the hash ID of the last commit

Given the above—and getting a bit lazy on purpose and drawing the connection from commit to commit as a line, instead of an arrow going from child to parent—we can now draw the `master` branch in like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
```

The *name* `master` simply contains the actual hash ID of existing commit `H`.

Let's add another name, `develop`, that *also contains hash ID `H`*, like this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, master
```

Now we have a small problem: which *name* are we going to use?  Here, Git uses the special name `HEAD` to remember which *branch name* to use, so let's update the drawing a bit:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

This represents the result after `git checkout master`: the *current branch name* is now `master`, and `master` selects commit `H`, so that's the commit we're using (and the branch name that we're using too).

If we run `git checkout develop` now, Git will switch to that branch.  That *name* still identifies commit `H`, so there's nothing else to change, but now we have:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- develop (HEAD), master
```

If we now make a new commit, Git will:

- package up all the files it knows about (this is where Git's *index* or *staging area* comes in, but we won't cover it at all here);
- add appropriate metadata, including your name as author and committer and "now" as the time stamps, but importantly, making commit `H` the *parent* of the new commit;
- use all of this to make a new commit, which we'll call `I`.

There's one more thing Git will do but let's draw this part now.  The result is:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I
```

What about the two names?  That's the one more thing: Git will write `I`'s hash ID into the *current name*.  If that's `develop`, we get this:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Note that `master` stayed in place, but the name `develop` has moved to point to the newest commit.

#### When two names identify the same commit, either name selects that commit

Note that initially, when `master` and `develop` both selected commit `H`, it didn't matter, in one sense, which one you used with `git checkout`.  Either way you got commit `H` as the current commit.  But when you make the *new* commit, now it matters, because Git is only going to update one branch *name*.  No one knows what the new commit's hash ID will be (because it depends in part on the exact second at which you make the commit), but once it's made, `develop` will hold that hash ID, if `develop` is the current *name*.

Note that if you now `git checkout master` and make another new commit, the name `master` will be the one updated this time:

```
...--F--G--H--J   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- develop
```

Let's assume for the moment that you *have not* done this, though.

#### Fast-forward

With the earlier picture in mind, let's run `git checkout master` now, and go back to working with commit `H`:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master (HEAD)
            \
             I   <-- develop
```

In this state, let's run `git merge develop` now.

Git will do the things it does for `git merge`—see below—and find that the *merge base* is commit `H`, which is also the current commit.  The other commit, `I`, is *ahead of* commit `H`.  These are the conditions under which Git can do a fast-forward operation.

A fast-forward is not an actual merge.  What happens is that Git says to itself: *If I did a real merge, I'd get a commit whose snapshot matches commit `I`.  So instead, I'll take a short cut, and just **check out** commit `I` while dragging the name `master` along with me.*  The result looks like this:

```
...--F--G--H
            \
             I   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

and there is now no reason to keep the kink in the drawing—we could make this all one straight row.

#### Real merges

Sometimes, the above kind of fast-forward-instead-of-merge trick just doesn't work.  Suppose you start with:

```
...--G--H   <-- develop, master (HEAD)
```

and make two new commits `I-J`:

```
          I--J   <-- master (HEAD)
         /
...--G--H   <-- develop
```

Now you `git checkout develop` and make two more commits `K-L`:

```
          I--J   <-- master
         /
...--G--H
         \
          K--L   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

At this point, no matter which name you give to `git checkout`, if you run `git merge` on the other name, there's no way to go *forward* from `J` to `L`, or vice versa.  From `J`, you have to back up to `I`, then go down to shared commit `H`, before you can go forward to `K` and then `L`.

This kind of merge, then, *cannot* be a fast-forward operation.  Git will instead do a real merge.

To perform a merge, Git uses:

- the current (`HEAD`) commit: let's make that `J` by doing `git checkout master` first;
- the other commit you name: let's use `git merge develop` to choose commit `L`;
- and one more commit, that Git finds on its own.

This last—or really, first—commit is the *merge base*, and the merge base is defined in terms of a graph operation known as Lowest Common Ancestor, but the short and understandable version is that Git works backwards from *both* commits to find the *best shared common ancestor*.  In this case, that's commit `H`: the point where the two branches diverge.  While commits `G` and earlier are also shared, they're not as good as commit `H`.

So Git will now:

- compare the merge base `H` snapshot with the `HEAD`/`J` snapshot, to see what we changed on `master`;
- compare the merge base `H` snapshot with the other/`L` snapshot, to see what they changed on `develop`; and
- *combine* the two sets of changes, and apply those to the merge base snapshot.

This is the process of merging, or *to merge* as a verb.  Git will do all of this on its own, if it can.  If it succeeds, Git will make a new commit, which we will call `M`:

```
          I--J
         /    \
...--G--H      M   <-- master (HEAD)
         \    /
          K--L   <-- develop
```

Note that new commit `M` points back to *both* commits `J` *and* `L`.  This is in fact what makes this new commit a merge commit.  Because a fast-forward is literally not possible, Git *must* make this commit, in order to achieve the merge.

#### You were initially doing fast-forwards

You started out with this kind of situation:

```
...--G--H   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
```

which then produced:

```
...--G--H   <-- master
         \
          I   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

You used `git checkout master; git merge develop` or similar to get:

```
...--G--H--I   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

after which you can repeat the process, making first `develop`, then both `develop` *and* `master`, name new commit `J`:

```
...--G--H--I--J   <-- master (HEAD), develop
```

But at this point you did something different: you did a `git revert` while on `master`.

The `git revert` command makes a new commit.  The new commit's snapshot is like the previous snapshot with one commit backed-out, as it were, so now you have:

```
                K   <-- master (HEAD)
               /
...--G--H--I--J   <-- develop
```

The snapshot in `K` probably matches that in `I` (so it re-uses all those files), but the commit number is all-new.

From here, you did `git checkout develop` and wrote a better commit than `J`, which we can call `L`:

```
                K   <-- master
               /
...--G--H--I--J--L   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

Then you went back to `master` and ran `git merge develop`.  This time, Git *had to* make a new *merge commit*.  So it did just that:

```
                K--M   <-- master (HEAD)
               /  /
...--G--H--I--J--L   <-- develop
```

Now, when you go back to `develop` and make new commits, you get the same pattern:

```
                K--M   <-- master
               /  /
...--G--H--I--J--L--N   <-- develop (HEAD)
```

When you switch back to `master` and `git merge develop`, Git must once again make a new merge commit.  Fast-forwarding is not possible, and instead you get:

```
                K--M--O   <-- master (HEAD)
               /  /  /
...--G--H--I--J--L--N   <-- develop
```

#### What you can do about this

Suppose you now run `git checkout develop && git merge --ff-only master`.  The first step selects `develop` as the current branch.  The second asks to merge with `master`.  This extra flag, `--ff-only`, tells Git: *but only do that if you can do it as a fast-forward.*

(We already believe that Git can do this as a fast-forward, so this `--ff-only` flag is just a safety check.  I think it's a good idea, though.)

Since a fast-forward *is* possible, you'll get this:

```
                K--M--O   <-- master, develop (HEAD)
               /  /  /
...--G--H--I--J--L--N
```

Note how the name `develop` has moved forward, to point to commit `O`, without adding a new merge commit.  This means that the next commit you make *on* `develop` will have `O` as its parent, like this:

```
                        P   <-- develop (HEAD)
                       /
                K--M--O   <-- master
               /  /  /
...--G--H--I--J--L--N
```

If you now `git checkout master; git merge develop` you'll get a fast-forward, with both names identifying new commit `P`, and you'll be back in that situation in which committing on `develop` allows a fast-forward.

#### Note that by doing this, you're essentially claiming that you don't need the name `develop` after all

If your work-pattern is:

- make new commit
- drag `master` forward to match

then all you need to do is make your new commits while on `master`.

There's nothing inherently *wrong* with doing the new commits on another name, and if this is only *sometimes* your work pattern, that's probably a good habit: using lots of branch names will help you later, and being in the habit of making a new name before starting on work is good.  You might want to consider using a name more meaningful than just `develop`, though.

In any case, note that what Git cares about here are the *commits*.  The *branch names* are just ways you can have Git help you *find* specific commits: the commit found by each name is the point at which you're doing work with that name.  The actual *branching*, if there is any, is a function of the commits you make.

To put it another way: **To make commits form into branches, you need branch names, but having branch names alone does not make commits form into branches.**  That is:

```
...--F--G--H   <-- master
            \
             I--J   <-- develop
```

gives you two "last" commits, but a single linear chain ending at commit `J`.  In one sense, there are two branches, one of which ends at `H` and one of which ends at `J`, but in another, there is only one branch, that ends at `J`.  We can add more names, pointing to existing commits:

```
...--F   <-- old
      \
       G--H   <-- master
           \
            I--J   <-- develop
```

and now there are three *names* (and three "last" commits) but the actual set of *commits* in the repository has not changed.  We just drew `F` on a line by itself so as to make the name `old` point to it.

Comment: Holy cow! Now *that's* a fountain of knowledge. Excellent. Beautiful. Clear as a bell. Solved my problem exactly. Worth a bounty, so have one on me. Thank you very much.

Comment: *"It seems likely that you were doing fast-forward operations before."* It turns out that's correct, although I didn't realize it at the time. Now with your help I know what to look out for if/when this happens again. But I noticed something... shouldn't this syntax `git checkout master; git merge develop` be `git checkout master && git merge develop` instead? I tried the former and received some Git error messages. The latter ran fine.

Comment: *"You might want to consider using a name more meaningful than just develop, though."* You are correct. FYI I normally do so, but in this single case I'm working on code that must be tested in a "production" environment (i.e. after installation). Thus, I'm committing and pushing every few minutes or more often; multiple branches would multiply the job's complexity exponentially. In other words, I need to stay "close to the metal," as it were. That said, much more of this and I might get fed up and just switch to `master` for the duration (now that I have your solution as perspective).

Comment: ...or I could create a feature branch and temporarily set that branch as a build trigger in my pipeline. Hm, I'll have to give that some thought. That might be the smart thing to do.

Comment: @InteXX: The sh / bash syntax `cmd1 && cmd2` means *run cmd2 if and only if cmd1 returns a successful exit status*, and is generally a good idea. I have no idea how to do that in Windows shells though. :-) The `cmd1; cmd2` means *run cmd1, then run cmd2 even if cmd1 fails*, so yes, the `&&` is better here (because `git checkout` can fail and if it does fail, that will stop the `git merge`).

Comment: *"The sh / bash syntax..."* Aha. I suspected as much, especially given the semicolon. In Windows the syntax only requires one `&`, but the behavior is the same as bash's `;`—one command right after the other, regardless of pass or fail. I don't think it's possible in Windows to do the `if-then-else` you describe, but I could be mistaken. Anyway, thanks again for the detailed explanation—it helps a lot. Several things came clear to me while reading it. Fine job there.